# Default value in an input tag at a particular position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know if this is possible or not and hence here's the part. Suppose I have an input tag like the following.

```
<input id="expiry" name="expiry" type="text" placeholder="MM/YY">
```

Now what I want is that the user should already see the '/' part, i.e when he types 1212, the textbox should become 12/12 automatically, can it be done if yes , how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recently I found a plugin that looks nice and I think it does what you're after, so I'm sharing it with you: http://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/

Comment: I think i was bit unclear in questioning but this is exactly what i was after. Please add as an answer instead of comment, i can just approve it. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I found a plugin that looks nice and I think it does what you're after, so I'm sharing it with you: [cleave.js](http://nosir.github.io/cleave.js)

Answer (score 3):

For an HTML/CSS-only approach, you could use two inputs, and style them with no borders on the inside edges:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="2">
<span> / </span>
<input type="text" maxlength="2">
```

With the `input` and `span` elements set to `display: inline-block;` and some styling of borders, this is a strong, semantic approach with no required Javascript.

Comment: I was already going through js solutions in my head, then i see this answer, it's good stuff, thanks:-)

Comment: if i had to use pure html like this, no point of questioning. I understand this is the best solution but not in my case though

Comment: You posted no code, and offered no explanation of what you "had" to use or might be able to use. These are fundamental concepts of SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="expiry" name="expiry" type="text" placeholder="MM/YY">
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#expiry").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
   if($('#expiry').val().length ==2){
   $('#expiry').val($('#expiry').val()+'/');
   }        
});

</script>
```

check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0x6npjhk/)

Comment: @nicael Basically he want auto slash('/') between his month and days what my code providing.use is free to enter his desire date

Comment: I get it, but your solution doesn't work properly. Have you tried removing the characters after typing them?

Answer (score -1):

try to use jquery mask plugin :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#expiry').mask('00/00');
});
```